# C# Receiving Packet in System.Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

In my Client Server Application i wondered how to make a packet and send it to the server via the Client

Then on the server i recognize which packet is this and send the proper replay

but suddenly i got across this topic and it make me worry if i may fall in this problem

> The Problem
>
> One of the most common beginner mistakes for people designing
>   protocols for TCP/IP is that they assume that message boundaries are
>   preserved. For example, they assume a single "Send" will result in a
>   single "Receive".
>
> Some TCP/IP documentation is partially to blame. Many people read
>   about how TCP/IP preserves packets - splitting them up when necessary
>   and re-ordering and re-assembling them on the receiving side. This is
>   perfectly true; however, a single "Send" does not send a single
>   packet.
>
> Local machine (loopback) testing confirms this misunderstanding,
>   because usually when client and server are on the same machine they
>   communicate quickly enough that single "sends" do in fact correspond
>   to single "receives". Unfortunately, this is only a coincidence.
>
> This problem usually manifests itself when attempting to deploy a
>   solution to the Internet (increasing latency between client and
>   server) or when trying to send larger amounts of data (requiring
>   fragmentation). Unfortunately, at this point, the project is usually
>   in its final stages, and sometimes the application protocol has even
>   been published!
>
> True story: I once worked for a company that developed custom client/server software.
>   The original communications code had made this
>   common mistake. However, they were all on dedicated networks with
>   high-end hardware, so the underlying problem only happened very
>   rarely. When it did, the operators would just chalk it up to "that
>   buggy Windows OS" or "another network glitch" and reboot. One of my
>   tasks at this company was to change the communication to include a lot
>   more information; of course, this caused the problem to manifest
>   regularly, and the entire application protocol had to be changed to
>   fix it. The truly amazing thing is that this software had been used in
>   countless 24x7 automation systems for 20 years; it was fundamentally
>   broken and no one noticed.

So how could i send something like AUTH_CALC,VALUE1=10,VALUE2=12 packet and receive it from the server in a safe way...

And if you wanna an example of what i am doing here it is below

[CLIENT]

```
Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1001:UN=user123&PW=123456")) //1001 is the ID
```

[SERVER]

```
private void OnReceivePacket(byte[] arg1, Wrapper Client)
{
    try
    {
        int ID;
        string V = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(arg1).Split(':')[0];
        int.TryParse(V, out ID);

        switch (ID)
        {
            case 1001://Login Packet
                AppendToRichEditControl("LOGIN PACKET RECEIVED");
                break;

            case 1002:
                //OTHER IDs
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch { }         
}
```

So is this is a good way to structure a Message and handling it on the server ?

Also which is better encoding to use ASCII or UTF8 ?

Comment: is this not clear 
So is this is a good way to structure a Message and handling it on the server ?

Also which is better encoding to use ASCII or UTF8 ?

Comment: i didn't edited it :D What i mean is the way i am using in sending and recognizing [server side] the packet is good, i mean the way of packed id and this things ?. or there is a better way to send a packet and receive it on the server ??

Comment: I'd rather `Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("#1001:UN=user123&PW=123456\r\n"))` or, better, its binary equivalent. As andrew correctly pointed out you need either headers or delimiters and you have to buffer and check for them server-side UNLESS you open-close the connection.

Comment: "Is this is a good way to structure a Message". No it isn't. It's not even a *way* to 'structure a message'. It is just some hopeful code that makes exactly the same mistakes as described in your quotation.

Comment: You just told no it isn't and did not provided me with any reference of how to structure a message also how to not fill in the same mistake !!!!

Comment: I answered the question you asked. If you have another question, ask it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can do is by using length indicator. Suppose you are sending a file of 10000 bytes, first send the length of the file and receive the ack i.e "OK" string from other side, then keep on sending 10,000 bytes chunk by chunk(may be u can take 4096 bytes). Send 4096 bytes each time for two time and send 2000 odd bytes on the last chunk. On the receiver side there is no gauranty that for one send you will receive the whole 4096 bytes, so you need to wait until u get 4096 bytes and then proceed with next 4096 bytes.